# Segmentation Fault (core dumped). In a Hash Table using separate chaining. (C++)

Tags: c++

I am currently creating a Hash Table that uses separate chaining as a collision resolution. I implemented a next pointer to the next node in the struct similar to how a linked list would be structured.

Whenever I attempt to access the next node's word I get a memory error saying Segmentation Fault (core dumped).

```
cout<<hashTable[5].next->word; //this line produces the memory error
```

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    string word;
    Node* next;
    bool empty;
};


void hashInsert(Node table[], string word){
    int index = 5; //should add hashFunction() if not testing
    Node* current = &table[index];
    if(table[index].empty){
        table[index].word = word;
        table[index].empty = false;
    }
    else{
        while(current->next != nullptr){
            current = current->next;
        }
        current = new Node();
        current->word = word;
        current->next = nullptr;
        current->empty = false;
        
    }
}


int main()
{
Node hashTable[10];
hashInsert(hashTable, "test");
hashInsert(hashTable, "test");
cout<<hashTable[5].next->word;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Node hashTable[10];
```

leaves its contents uninitialized. This makes some of the stuff in `hashInsert` [a bit more of an adventure](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) than you want to see in a computer program. Use

```
Node hashTable[10] = {};
```

to [Zero Initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) the array and get more predictability.

But this doesn't solve all of the problems. Zero Initializing will set `empty` to false, which it isn't. You need a default constructor (or [default member initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) on the members) to force the value to `true` or to reverse the logic.

When you look closer at either approach, you realize the `empty` flag is only needed because the first node in the list might not be in use. But what if there was no first node if there is no need for the first node? `empty`'s job could be handled with a null pointer.

```
Node * hashTable[10] = {}; // treat each entry in the hash table like a next
                           // without the rest of the node
```

This lets you shrink `hashInsert` to

```cpp
void hashInsert(Node * table[], string word) {
    int index = 5; //should add hashFunction() if not testing
    Node *current = table[index]; //
    if (table[index] == nullptr)
    {
        table[index] = new Node{word, nullptr};
    }
    else
    {
        while (current->next != nullptr)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current = new Node{word, nullptr};
    }
}
```

Note:  `Node{word, nullptr};` is using [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) to allow us to create the `Node` and set all of its members in one shot. Very handy.

But this doesn't work because `current` is a locally scoped automatic variable, so the new `Node` assigned to it is lost as soon as the function returns. We need something smarter here.

Ranoiaetep suggested `current->next = new Node();`. This will work, but we can get even smarter.

```cpp
void hashInsert(Node * table[], string word) {
    int index = 5; //should add hashFunction() if not testing
    Node **current = &table[index]; // point at the next pointer! Now we know 
                                    // the correct place to insert in ALL cases
    if (*current == nullptr)
    {
        *current = new Node{word, nullptr};
    }
    else
    {
        while (*current != nullptr)
        {
            current = &(*current)->next;
        }
        *current = new Node{word, nullptr};
    }
}
```

Bit in this version you might notice that `if (*current == nullptr)` and `while (*current != nullptr)` really aren't that different. In the `if` we add a new node when there is no node. In the `while`,  we look for no node and then add a new node. Either way, no node means add a node. We may be able to combine them.

```cpp
void hashInsert(Node * table[], string word) {
    int index = 5; //should add hashFunction() if not testing
    Node **current = &table[index]; 
    while (*current != nullptr) // look for end of list
    {
        current = &(*current)->next;
    }
    *current = new Node{word, nullptr}; // add to end of list
}
```

Woot. 4 lines of code and a couple braces.

The whole thing together looks like

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    string word;
    Node *next;
};

void hashInsert(Node * table[], string word) {
    int index = 5; //should add hashFunction() if not testing
    Node **current = &table[index]; 
    while (*current != nullptr)
    {
        current = &(*current)->next;
    }
    *current = new Node{word, nullptr}; 
}

int main() {
    Node * hashTable[10] = {};
    hashInsert(hashTable, "test");
    hashInsert(hashTable, "test");
    cout << hashTable[5]->next->word;
}
```

Comment: How would you go about accessing the word member of the "current" pointer? I want to add an equality statement saying that if the word from parameter is equal to the current word when traversing, then I don't need to add it again.

Comment: Just like `(*current)->next`. You dereference `current `, changing it from a pointer to a pointer to a `Node` to a pointer to a `Node` and then use the `->` operator to access the member.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things:

1. `bool empty` is defaulted to `false`, which I'm assuming you meant the opposite.
2. After calling:

```
while(current->next != nullptr){
    current = current->next;
}
```

Your `current` is actually the last non `nullptr`. So any subsequent calls you made were done to the first `Node` you inserted.

After the `while` loop, you would need to add:

```
current->next = new Node();
current = current->next;
```

---

#### Edit:

Without changing other structures, here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    string word;
    Node* next;
    bool empty = true; // empty is now defaulted to true
};


void hashInsert(Node table[], string word){
    int index = 5;
    Node* current = &table[index];
    if(table[index].empty){
        table[index].word = word;
        table[index].empty = false;
    }
    else{
        while(current->next != nullptr){
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = new Node(); // A new Node is added after current
        current = current->next; // Now current is set to the next Node
        current->word = word;
        // current->next = nullptr; // This is not needed
        current->empty = false;
    }
}


int main()
{
    Node hashTable[10];
    hashInsert(hashTable, "test");
    hashInsert(hashTable, "test");
    cout << hashTable[5].word << ", ";
    cout << hashTable[5].next->word;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the improvements! That still doesn't fix the memory access problem though. Do you have any ideas on how I could fix that?

Comment: @Jack Check the edit if that's the code you end up having. It works fine for me.

Comment: @Jack or [here](https://repl.it/@Ranoiaetep/WhirlwindCoordinatedExecutable) for live

Comment: Ranoiaetep you'll also need `Node* next = nullptr;` or the `while(current->next != nullptr)` tests will see uninitialized pointers and fail. This could be what @Jack is tripping over.

Comment: @user4581301 I thought uninitialized pointer would be defaulted to `nullptr`. Would it work if you just use `while(current->next)`? Else I would need to change a lot of thing :(

Comment: Uninitialized pointer is like an `int`. If you don't set it or force it to be set, you get whatever circumstances happened to put there. Initialize it and  `while(current->next)` should work, but only because you're previously tested nd proved that `current` isn't null.